# Jasmine SpyObj function is undefined

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy

I am testing a component which includes a service. I want to mock the service. Following the documentation I have setup my mock like this:

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let mockApplicationsService: jasmine.SpyObj<ApplicationsService>;
  const applicationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApplicationService, ['getApplications']);
  
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declaration: [DashboardComponent],
        providers: [
          {
            provide: ApplicationsService,
            useValue: {applicationsServiceSpy}
          }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockApplicationsService = TestBed.inject(ApplicationsService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ApplicationsService>;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  it('should create the app', () => {
    console.log(mockApplicationsService);
    console.log(mockApplicationsService.getApplications);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })
  
}
```

When I run test I get an error `this.applicationsService.getApplications is not a function`. This is saying that the component has an applicationsService but it does not have a method called `getApplications`. Similarly I can see in the browser console of the karma test runner that mockApplicationsService is an Object called `applicationsServiceSpy` with a function called `getApplications`. But the second console log returns `undefined`.

[image]

Is there something that I am doing wrong when mocking this service?

Comment: Yes, you're passing an _object_ as the value to use, using object shorthand (equivalent to `{applicationsServiceSpy: applicationsServiceSpy}`), rather than the spy itself. You can _see that_ in what you've logged.

Comment: Oh man!! I've been stuck on that forever! Thanks for pointing that out